# Rails Carierwave deafult_url doesn't return fallback image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading

I need to render fallback img if object doesnt have own.
The Carierwave uploader looks like:

```
 def default_url(*args)
   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_') 
 end
```

I'm render a img like: `<%= image_tag @teams.last.team_img %>`

But the pages show only text: ***"Default"***

JS console says: *http://localhost:3000/images/fallback/default.png 404 (Not Found)*

But I created dir fallback in app/assets/images and put there dafault.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails's assets compile all static assets into path `/assets`

So, for your situation, the `default_url` pointing to wrong URL. It should be:

```
 def default_url(*args)
   "/assets/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_') 
 end
```

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know some useful placeholders for images? Should I use something with JS?